# Java async socket IO

Tags: java, asynchronous, io, nio

I've looked all over but I could not find a good example explaining NIO2 or how to do asynchronous IO with Java sockets. For example, if I want to speed up a web crawler by allowing threads to use async IO to read from sockets instead of regular synchronous IO, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NIO2 is not faster than synchronous I/O. It allows to run many connections (tens of thousands) with a few threads. If you can afford to spend a thread for each connection, use synchronous I/O - it is simpler to program.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Can you clarify when would it be appropriate to use NIO2?

Comment: In other words, when would it be better to have fewer threads with many connections, verses more threads with a connection for each thread?

Comment: Threads take a lot of memory, so it is unpractical to have >1000 threads on a computer, and even powerful server machine hardly can bear more than 10000 threads at once. So the memory consumption is the main criteria. I would say that for <100 connections I would definitely use one thread per connection, and for >100 I would think if I can spend so much memory for threads.